# transform all but one variable in data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `data.frame` that looks like this

```
set.seed(1)
s <- 100
example_df <- data.frame(id=1:s) %>%
       mutate(x=sample(0:10, s, replace=T),
              x1=sample(0:10, s, replace=T),
              x2=sample(0:10, s, replace=T),
              x3=sample(0:10, s, replace=T),
              x4=sample(0:10, s, replace=T))
```

Now what I'd like to do is the following:

```
example_df %>%
       mutate(d_x1 = (x-x1)^2,
              d_x2 = (x-x2)^2,
              d_x3 = (x-x3)^2,
              d_x4 = (x-x4)^2)
```

How do I achieve the same result without explicitly spelling out every operation? `mutate_at`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `mutate_at` like

```
library(dplyr)

example_df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(matches("x\\d+")), list(d = ~(x - .)^2)) %>% head

#  id x x1 x2 x3 x4 x1_d x2_d x3_d x4_d
#1  1 8  6  7  6  9    4    1    4    1
#2  2 3  7  3  1  5   16    0    4    4
#3  3 6  4  9  4 10    4    9    4   16
#4  4 0  5  7  9  1   25   49   81    1
#5  5 1  7  4  9  4   36    9   64    9
#6  6 6  0  4  7  3   36    4    1    9
```

Or in base R, we can use `lapply`

```
cols <- grep("x\\d+", names(example_df), value = TRUE)
example_df[paste0("d_", cols)] <- lapply(example_df[cols], function(x) 
                                   (example_df$x - x)^2)
```

Comment: If you want to work on all the columns except `x`, `mutate_at(vars(-x))` works also